# Seven Mitzvos D'Rabanan

Tags: mitzvah, derabanan

I heard there are 620 letters in the Aseres Hadibros which corresponds to the 613 Mitzvos of the Torah and 7 Mitzvos D'Rabanan. What are the Seven Mitzvos D'Rabanan - שבע מצוות דרבנן? Is there a easy way to remember them? Is there any disagreement as to what the seven are?

Comment: "The laws are codified in the Shulchan Aruch in Orach Chaim 366, 408 and 527." I don't have a text in front of me so I can't gloss it -- sorry.

Comment: @Danno Try [OC 366](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2101), [OC 408](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2129), and [OC 527](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2884).

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13035&st=&pgnum=101&hilite=

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rav Baruch Halperin in Sefer Mitzvat Hashem (beginning on p. 149 of [this edition](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39013&st=&pgnum=149&hilite=)) gives the list below and explains each in detail! A clearer text of Rav Halperin's list is included as an appendix to [this edition](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4V9geGSKAJlSU9mTWcwYmlRUXVSb2ZMMlhCaDNZQQ/edit?pli=1) of the Chinuch (p394).

The 7 Mitzvos are:

1. Berachos - Reciting Berachos
2. Netilas Yadayim - washing your hands
3. Eruvin - allowing one to carry within an Eruv and walk further on Shabbos through an Eruv Techumin
4. Reciting Hallel on festivals
5. Ner Shabbos - Shabbos candles
6. Megilla - on Purim
7. Chanuka - lighting the Menora.

There are many mnemonics for remembering them.
One from [Sefer Keser Torah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42170&pgnum=15) is:

אש"ר לרע"ך

```
א - אור (חנוכה)
ש - שבת (נר)
ר - רנה (הלל)
ל - לקריאה (מגילה)
ר - רחיצה (נטילת ידיים)
ע - ערובין
כ - כברכותיך
```

More can be found at [wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%9F)

Answer (score 4):

[Chasam Sofer - Parshas Yisro - Asher Lraiacha](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21623&st=&pgnum=86) says that the seven Mitzvos are as follows.

א - Aveilus - Seven days of Aveilus

ש - Simcha - Seven days of Simchas Chasan and Kallah

ר - Rechitza - Netilas Yadayim

ל - Lechem - Not to eat Pas Akum or Bishul Akum

ר - Reshuyos - This is Eruvin which combines Reshuyos

ע - Amalaik - Reading the Megila, which goes on the eradication of haman and the people that were killed on the 13th of Adar, which were from Amalaik

כ - Kohanim - This alludes to the miracle of Chanuka which was established by the Kohanim.

I see [Zvi has answered](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53632/759) with some different Mitzvos from another reliable source, so I guess there is some disagreement as to exactly what these seven Mitzvos are.