# Minhagim and Mitzvot Derabanan

Tags: minhag, derabanan

I was having a discussion with someone about whether we have an actual obligation in the 7 Mitzvot Derabanan. The conclusion we came to was that we are obligated in them because in the past, the entire Jewish community accepted them as a Minhagim which then made it binding for us, even today.

Are there any problems with saying that the 7 Mitzvot Derabanan are Minhagim?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.17.11?lang=bi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the basis that allows Rabbis to create laws?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65924/what-is-the-basis-that-allows-rabbis-to-create-laws)

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53631/seven-mitzvos-drabanan

Comment: +1. This seems to be a valid question (based on the the principle, mentioned, for example, by the Rambam re. *takanas 'Ezra* "ולא פשטה תקנה זו בכל ישראל ולא היה כח ברוב הציבור לעמוד בה לפיכך בטלה"), and not a duplicate of the linked ones.

Comment: I would say that it is still different. While minhagim may change based on the various circumstances, takkanot cannot be changed and are treated as mitzvos themselves. As an example, certain takkanot require a bracha while minhagim do not. Examples of this are Chanukah and Purim.

Comment: @sabbahillel That may be an oversimplification and an overgeneralization. For example, the mechanics of how *takanas 'Ezra* changed in the time of R' Yehuda ben Beseira are understood differently by different authorities.