# Is there a mention of the 7 Mitzvot deRabanan in the Talmud or Midrash?

Tags: talmud-gemara, midrash, mitzvah, derabanan

Is there a mention of the 7 Mitzvot deRabanan in the Talmud or Midrash? Or does this come from other, later sources?

Comment: Are you asking whether this a reference to a specific set of seven mitzvot derabanan? What about individual references to (some of) the mitzvot within this list?

Comment: @Joel K The individual links to them are also interesting. But why exactly these mitzvos? After all, the mitzvos derabonon are much more.

Comment: See קובץ בית אהרן וישראל - No. 35 תשנ"א סיון-תמוז (p. 97 and on) for a full discussion of the various opinions of what the list of "Seven" actually is comprised of. https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13035&st=&pgnum=93

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53631/759

Answer (score 1):

Per this [Wikipedia article](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%9F#:%7E:text=%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%99%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%AA%3A%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%2C%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%99%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA%2C%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94.) the original source for this is [Sefer Keser Torah](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44849&pgnum=228) by Rabbi David Vital. He lives in the first half of the 16th century.

Comment: One of the answers in the linked question says that the list is also recorded in the Chinuch (although I haven't been able to find that myself). If that is true, then it would predate the 16th century by a few hundred years.

Comment: @Salmononius2 at the top of the list in the Chinuch it says מספר מצות השם

Comment: @Salmononius2 As WFB points out, that is an addition to the [Sefer Hachinuch](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34302&st=&pgnum=394&hilite=) from the Sefer Mitzvas Hashem. Mitzvas Hashem was published in 5691 = 1931.

Comment: But why are these 7 mitzvos so special? What is this opinion based on?

Comment: @Dankl-FranlbarUri-Hirschl that was not your question. Your question was the source for these Mitzvas, which was answered. If you want to know why these 7 Mitzvas are so special then [please ask a separate question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

I have a negative source - a rishon who enumerates the Mitzvos Rirabanan as five. If there were a Talmudic source for seven he certainly would have brought that number, and it is unlikely that a midrashic source would have been missed. (But there are so many midrashim that it is hard to rule out the possibility.)

[Smag, introduction to Eruvin](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_Mitzvot_Gadol%2C_Rabbinic_Commandments%2C_Laws_of_Eruvin.1?lang=bi):

> אחרי שסיימנו מ״ע של תורה נחל לבאר מצות עשה שהם מד״ס ומהם מדברי נביאים והם חמש מצות. מצות עירובין. מצות אבל. מצות תשעה באב. מצות מגילה. מצות חנוכה. וכבר בארנו מצות נטילת ידים שהיא מד״ס בהל׳ ברכות [לעיל].
>
> After we have finnished the positive commandments from the Torah, let us begin to explain the the mitzvos that are from divrey sofrim and that are dirabanan, and they are five mitzvos...

Comment: The Rambam also mentions only five Mitzvos Derabanan (but doesn't quantify them with the number 5). See Yad (beginning, end of Minyan HaMitzvos):  ויש מצוות אחרות שנתחדשו אחר מתן תורה, וקבעו אותן נביאים וחכמים, ופשטו בכל ישראל, כגון: מקרא מגילה, ונר חנוכה, ותענית תשעה באב, ועירובין, וידים. Perhaps his use of the word "כגון" is intended to imply that his list is not exhaustive.

Comment: The Smag actually seems to have SIX, in his list. The 5 that he enumerates here +  נטילת ידים, which he already had preciously mentioned in Hilchos Brachos.